# Can you like a facebook post with a like button on a different website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

What I'm trying to do is pull in the feed from two facebook pages and display all the posts on my page. I was able to do that successfully using the Graph API and pulling the posts as JSON objects.

Next I wanted to add the Facebook Like button to point to those posts and have it add the like to the current number of likes on the post. So far I've been able to get it to work with posts of status_type `mobile_status_update` and `added_video` by dynamically generating a Like button using the url in each post object as the `href` for the Like button.
Like this:

```
like = '<fb:like class="fblike" href="'+value.actions[1].link+'" colorscheme="light" layout="standard" action="like" show_faces="false" send="false"></fb:like>';
```

This doesn't seem to work on posts of type `added_photos` and `shared_story` though. If I try clicking the Like button for the `added_photos` it will 'Like' then 'Unlike' immediately, registering nothing.

Basically my question is if there is a way to make a Like button on an external site that will update on Facebook?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: i'm also looking for this functionality. please let us know if you found anything

Comment: I've found this issue too. It's quite frustrating as I'm wanting to make a custom-styled page feed...